# Plot all columns from two separate dataframes by group in Python

Tags: python, pandas, plot, pandas-groupby

I have two dataframes with lots of columns and rows with the same structure as the examples below:

df1:

```
Time    Group   Var1    Var2    Var3
1/1/2016    A   0.1     1.1     2.1
2/1/2016    A   0.2     1.2     2.2  
1/1/2016    B   3.5     4.5     5.5
2/1/2016    B   3.6     4.6     5.6
```

df2:

```
Time     Group  Var1    Var2    Var3
1/1/2016    A   0.3     1.3     2.3
2/1/2016    A   0.4     1.4     2.4
1/1/2016    B   3.7     4.7     5.7
2/1/2016    B   3.8     4.8     5.8
```

I would like write a code that created one plot per column having `Time` as x-axis for each group and plotting columns with the same name from each dataframe on the same plot.

I was able to write a code that did this but not varying by group:

```
df1_agg = df1.groupby(by =['Time']).sum()
df2_agg = df2.groupby(by =['Time']).sum()

def plots_all_columns(col_names, filename):
    with PdfPages(filename) as pdf:
        for i in col_names:
            plt.figure()
            df1_agg[i].plot(label="df1", legend=True, title = i)
            df2_agg[i].plot(label="df2", legend=True)
            pdf.savefig()
            plt.close('all')
```

How could I do the same as above but keeping the Group dimension in my dataframe? I have lots of groups so I would need a separate plot for each group category.

Thank you.

Comment: So you just want to plot two `df` in a plot which contain the same `columns name`?

Comment: I want to plot the column from each df with the same name on the same plot.

Comment: So it means each `df` share the data when the column name eaqual?

Comment: no, the data is different, I want to plot the two lines together in the same plot.

Comment: Than I will advise you to merege the two `df` first and than `df.plot()` may get what you want.